# Biblatex: Authors in small caps and bold in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bold, small-caps

I am using `scrreprt` KOMA-class with `biblatex`.

I have my citations and bibliography set up as desired:

[image]

However, one detail is missing: I would like the authors in the bibliography to be both small caps AND bold (right now, they are small caps only.)

Is there a way to achieve this?

I have spent some time doing trial and error and scanning the biblatex documentation, but did not find what I needed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright, chapterprefix, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,headheight=15pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry} 

\usepackage[automark,headsepline=off]{scrlayer-scrpage}  % use document with \pagestyle{scrheadings}

%%% Deutsche Zeichen und Schrift
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % deutsche Trennregeln
\usepackage{lmodern}    % fixes bug with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}; ändert Schriftart zudem in Latin Modern
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % für europäische Autoren ratsam; % wichtig für Trennung von Wörtern mit Umlauten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[T1,hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true,  linktoc=all,    
    %linkcolor=beierblau, 
    citecolor=beierblau, filecolor=beierblau, urlcolor=beierblau, breaklinks=false,
    bookmarksopen=true, colorlinks, linkcolor = black}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}        % needed to help hyperlinks direct correctly;
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{beierblau}{RGB}{0,0,255}


%%% bibliography
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber,
%alphabetic --> see https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/biblatex_bibliography_styles; https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Biblatex_citation_styles
 refsegment=chapter, % benutze automatisch Kapitel als Biobliographie-Abschnitte... (refsegment makes sure that identical references have the same label throughout the whole document; as opposed to refsection)
% scauthors = true 
 ]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=true,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=999,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,labeldate=true,uniquelist=minyear}

%% set borders
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{12pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0cm}
%\setlength{\bibhang}{0.2cm} rückt mehrere Zeilen ein

%% fix sorting
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

%% no "quotes" around titles of chapters/article titles; text-style of title in bibliography 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, book, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, misc, thesis, unpublished]{title}{\textit{#1}}    % \textit for italic style titles; \textnormal for regular text

%% titles of articels and incollections not italic
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\textnormal{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{\textnormal{#1}}

%% separation style between authors
\AtBeginBibliography{%
    \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
    \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    andothers = {et\addspace al\adddotspace},%
    andmore = {et\addspace al\adddotspace},%
}

%% Authors in small caps in citation and bibliography
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

%% Format of punctuation after author+year
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{
%   \mkbibbold
    {\adddotspace}}     % \addcolon\space

%%Add bib resource
\addbibresource{Literatur/citavi.bib} 


%%% Example bibliography
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Giancoli,
        Author    = {Douglas C. Giancoli},
        Publisher = {Pearson},
        Title     = {Physics for Scientists \& Engineers},
        Year      = {2014},
        Date-Added = {2015-10-05 12:23:12 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2015-10-05 12:23:50 +0000},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test-Kapitel}
Some \cite{Giancoli} text \autocite{Giancoli}

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibintoc, title={Literatur}]  


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the used font for the family name of the entries in the bibliography only use the following just before your `\printbibliogrphy`:

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{#1}}}
```

Note that the correct macro name is `\mkbibnamefamily` not `\mkbibnamelast`. The latter is just for legacy support and doesn't work after `\begin{document}`. But  `lmodern` doesn't support bold smallcaps.

The `biblatex` commands for the formatting of names are:

```
\mkbibnamefamily
\mkbibnamegiven
\mkbibnameprefix
\mkbibnamesuffix
```

**Note:** To get something that looks like bold smallcaps, you might use the `contour` package if your font doesn't support them, but be aware that this might result in ugly looking output:

```
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{0.01em}% adjust how bold it'll get
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\contour{black}{\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\contour{black}{\textsc{#1}}}
```

This results in the following (upper is with `contour`, the lower is `\textbf{Giancoli}` for comparison)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The tecnical answer is to add `\textbf{...}` to the definition for:

```
%% Authors in small caps in citation and bibliography
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textbf{\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textbf{\textsc{#1}}}
```

but the problem is your used font family latin modern.  It does **not** support a font for bold **and** small caps.

To get that displayed you need to use a font supporting a font for bold and small caps ... And sorry, I do not know a font supporting this ...

Your code has some errors (useage of depreciated options).  Please see the following corrected MWE (see `<======` for important code changings, and please see that I changed the order of called packages!):

```
%%% Example bibliography
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Giancoli,
        Author    = {Douglas C. Giancoli},
        Publisher = {Pearson},
        Title     = {Physics for Scientists \& Engineers},
        Year      = {2014},
        Date-Added = {2015-10-05 12:23:12 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2015-10-05 12:23:50 +0000},
    }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[%
  12pt, twoside, openright, chapterprefix, numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[%
  left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,headheight=15pt,
  includeheadfoot
]{geometry} 

\usepackage[automark,headsepline=off]{scrlayer-scrpage}  % use document with \pagestyle{scrheadings}

%%% Deutsche Zeichen und Schrift
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % deutsche Trennregeln
\usepackage{lmodern}    % fixes bug with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}; ändert Schriftart zudem in Latin Modern
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % für europäische Autoren ratsam; % wichtig für Trennung von Wörtern mit Umlauten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{beierblau}{RGB}{0,0,255}

\usepackage[T1,hyphens]{url}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[% 
  style=authoryear, 
  backend=biber,
  refsegment=chapter, % benutze automatisch Kapitel als Biobliographie-Abschnitte... (refsegment makes sure that identical references have the same label throughout the whole document; as opposed to refsection)
% scauthors = true 
]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  giveninits=true, % <==================================================
  maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=999,
  isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,
  labeldateparts=true, % <==============================================
  uniquelist=minyear
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}   
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true,  linktoc=all,    
    %linkcolor=beierblau, 
    citecolor=beierblau, filecolor=beierblau, urlcolor=beierblau, breaklinks=false,
    bookmarksopen=true, colorlinks, linkcolor = black}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}        % needed to help hyperlinks direct correctly;
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}


%% set borders
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{12pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0cm}
%\setlength{\bibhang}{0.2cm} rückt mehrere Zeilen ein

%% fix sorting
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % <===========================

%% no "quotes" around titles of chapters/article titles; text-style of title in bibliography 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, book, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, misc, thesis, unpublished]{title}{\textit{#1}}    % \textit for italic style titles; \textnormal for regular text

%% titles of articels and incollections not italic
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\textnormal{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{\textnormal{#1}}

%% separation style between authors
\AtBeginBibliography{%
    \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
    \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    andothers = {et\addspace al\adddotspace},%
    andmore = {et\addspace al\adddotspace},%
}

%% Authors in small caps in citation and bibliography
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textbf{\textsc{#1}}} % <===========
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textbf{\textsc{#1}}} % <===========
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

%% Format of punctuation after author+year
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{
% \mkbibbold
  {\adddotspace}}     % \addcolon\space


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test-Kapitel}
Some \cite{Giancoli} text \autocite{Giancoli}

\printbibliography[%
  segment=\therefsegment, 
  heading=subbibintoc, 
  title={Literatur}
]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: That won't work (at least not if used after the preamble so that it only affects the bibliography).

Comment: Do you get bold small caps in the document at all? Also, I think the intended use _is_ in the preamble.