# Biblatex and small capitals for surname

Tags: biblatex, small-caps

Since none of the answers (like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396304/biblatex-authors-in-small-caps-and-bold-in-bibliography)) did not work for me, please, take a look on following. In my document I have this (short example for clearance)

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber
,style=iso-numeric
,sortlocale=cs_CZ
,bibencoding=UTF8
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{file}

\begin{document}
\cite{some item}
\printblibliography
\end{document}
```

And I would like to typset surnames with small caps. Suggested use of

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

before `\printblibliography` is not working. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to have caps in bibliography only, the "ISO 690 biblatex style" redefines `\mkbibnamefamily` with:

```
\newcommand{\familynameformat}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}{\familynameformat}%
}
```

According to the comments on `iso.bbx` right above these definitions:

```
% Thanks Moewew for sugesting this. Make uppercase names only in bibliography.
% Default name format is ALL-CAPS
% use something like
% \let\familynameformat=\textsc
% to change this
```

Following this advice, you could use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
backend=biber
,style=iso-numeric
,sortlocale=cs_CZ
,bibencoding=UTF8
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\let\familynameformat=\textsc

\begin{document}
\cite{aksin,angenendt,baez/article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: This answer was edited to reflect changes in `biblatex-iso690`, in case you are using an older version of it, check the edit history.

Comment: This is really clear solution, sir :) Thank you

Comment: Apparently, the command has been renamed: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553351/35864. `\lastnameformat` is now `\familynameformat` (in line with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).

Comment: @moewe Updated!

Comment: Thank you very much.