# biblatex: print surname in small capitals

Tags: biblatex

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408533) solution to print all surnames in small capitals, but unfortunately this method doesn't work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
backend=biber
,style=iso-numeric
,sortlocale=cs_CZ
,bibencoding=UTF8
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\let\lastnameformat=\textsc

\begin{document}
\cite{aksin,angenendt,baez/article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: surnames are not in small capitals]

Has anyone an idea whats going on? I'm using the latest texlive on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the command has been changed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
backend=biber
,style=iso-numeric
,sortlocale=cs_CZ
,bibencoding=UTF8
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\let\familynameformat=\textsc

\begin{document}
\cite{aksin,angenendt,baez/article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: this works for me, thank you!