# Biblatex: Adjust case of authors family names

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, small-caps

I am using the geschichtsfrkl style which prints the family names of authors in small caps.
I want the author names to printed normally, that is the first letter capitalised and the rest lower case, for example as the apa style does.

So far I tried to renew the `\mkbibnamefamily` command in various ways, based on the solution in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396304/biblatex-authors-in-small-caps-and-bold-in-bibliography), but that got me nowhere. I also had a look at the geschichtsfrkl.bbx file but could not find where the names are put into small caps.

So this is what my citations look like with the MWE below at the moment.
[image: Author family names with small caps]

Below is the style of family names I want. Note that I do not want to change to order of names, nor do I want given names to be abbreviated. This is simply to illustrate that I don't want the family names in small caps.
[image: Author family names with normal capitalisation]

As a test I tried to simply make the family name lowercase with this code, that also does not work:

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\lowercase{#1}}
```

Probably, I am misunderstanding how `\mkbibnamefamily` and `renewcommand` work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=german]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=geschichtsfrkl, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\lowercase{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{erlerStraftheorieZychaRegister1998,
  title = {Straftheorie - Zycha: Register},
  author = {Erler, Adalbert},
  location = {{Berlin}},
  date = {1998},
}

@book{ganshofWasIstLehnswesen1975,
  title = {Was ist das Lehnswesen?},
  author = {Ganshof, F. L.},
  location = {{Darmstadt}},
  edition = {4},
  date = {1975},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{ganshofWasIstLehnswesen1975} \\
\fullcite{erlerStraftheorieZychaRegister1998} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.bbx` file contains a command:

```
\newcommand*{\autorenschriftart}{\scshape}%
```

The `.cbx` file contains the command:

```
\newcommand*{\citeautorenschriftart}{\scshape}%
```

These macros are what introduces the small caps for names. It's therefore sufficient to renew these command to do nothing:

```
\renewcommand*{\autorenschriftart}{}%
\renewcommand*{\citeautorenschriftart}{}%
```

[image: output]

Comment: Ok, that was rather easy and works fine on fullcitations. However, on subsequent citations where a shortened citations is inserted it will use the small caps again. \scshape appears only once in the bbx though, so I am again at a loss what to look for.

Comment: @FChris I've updated the answer. See if that solves the problem.

Comment: that solves it, thank you very much. I think I have to read up on bbx vs cbx files, it did not even occur to me to look at the cbx.

Comment: The `.bbx` file supports the bibliography formatting and the `.cbx` file supports the citation callouts.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I never thought to think about them separately, I always assumed they will look the same anyways, but when you think about it, of course there might be differences.